# Converse of Taylor expansion theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

The Taylor theorem states, that if a function $f$ is $n$-times differentiable at point $a$, it has a unique expansion
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f^{(k)}(a) \frac{(x-a)^k}{k!} + o((x-a)^n)$$
Suppose now we are given a function $g$, which can be written in the form
$$
g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k (x-a)^k + o((x-a)^n)
$$
Is it true that $g$ will be $n$-times differentiable? Observe that because of uniqueness in that case we must have $g^{(k)}(a) = a_k k!$.

The problem can be simplified by subtracting the polynomial $ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k (x-a)^k$ and making a substitution $t = x-a$. Then the question is, if $h(t) = o(t^n)$ is $h$ n-times differentiable at zero?

P.S.
Feel free to use the Lagrange form, and make stronger assumptions if that leads to the solution.

Comment: with stronger assumptions, the answer is yes; see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/88501).

Comment: OMG, MSE and MO should have a common database of asked questions to avoid such duplicates! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

No, in fact, it doesn't even have to be 2-times differentiable. Take
$$h(t) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)t^{n+1} $$
where $1_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ is the Dirichlet function. Clearly $h(t) = o(t^n)$, however, the function is not even continuous in any point other than $0$. Hence, it can't be differentiable in those points. Therefore the second derivative does not exist anywhere.

Comment: Actually, I came up with this counterexample as soon as I posted the question. When posting the question I genuinely believed the answer is yes.